# How to stop sounds?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

How to stop this sound ? :

```
MySound.play(0,100,null);
```

Answer (score 4):

`play` returns a `SoundChannel`, which has a `stop()` method.  See [Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()).

> Generates a new SoundChannel object to
>   play back the sound. This method
>   returns a SoundChannel object, which
>   you access to stop the sound and to
>   monitor volume.

Comment: this didn't work for me. it ran and all, but didn't stop the sound from playing

Answer (score 3):

```
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = MySound.play(0, 100, null);
...
soundChannel.stop();
```